# mysql inner join not working as expected

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

Sorry about this. There are a million posts about this. Somehow, I am still missing something. Simple inner join exactly as this: 
http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/inner-join-with-multiple-tables.php

Clueless what the problem is. Just trying to add the org to the machine record. 
I expect that if there is no match on user_name, the machine record will be dropped, or not, but either way, <= number of records in machines. Getting multiples. Machines.machine_name and user_name are not unique in machines as each machine has multiple software packages tracked.

select users2.org, machines.User_name, machines.Machine_name, machines.model, machines.program, machines.version 
from machines inner join users2 on users2.user_name = machines.User_name

Comment: ah, one more. this is a bit simplified in that the machines table is not unique on machine_name. There are actually 10 to 50 records with the same machine name to include machines.program, machines.version for software on the machine. I want all the machine records.

Comment: can you share your schema?

Comment: describe machines;
Machine_name | varchar(50),
| User_name    | varchar(21)
| model        | varchar(50) 
| publisher    | varchar(100) 
| program      | varchar(255)
| version      | varchar(255)
| product_ID   | varchar(255)
describe users2;

| user_name              | varchar(25) 
| org                    | varchar(5)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to aggregate here because you will get a cartesian product for all of the machines that share a `user_name`:

```
select users2.org, 
       machines.User_name,
       machines.Machine_name, 
       machines.model 
from machines 
inner join users2 on users2.user_name = machines.User_name
GROUP BY users2.org, machines.User_name, machines.Machine_name, machines.model
```

Comment: am def getting a cartesian product here. Each user should have 1 machine. Each user/machine should have multiple records in the machines table. some records in each table are missing actual user_name but they have a default value like 'missing'.

Comment: Yeah that's what you need the `GROUP BY` in order to reduce the duplicate values. You can do it like I have it in my answer to aggregate the `machines` table before you join it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your input. The issue was that somehow when the data was massaged (user_name was originally email in 1 case and windows network id in the other), the missing user_names in both tables got changed to ' '. This caused join matches all over the place that I was not expecting. The missing user_name fields were supposed to have different default values. I fixed the default values in the machines table and excluded them with "where machines.User_name <> 'Unknown';" Now I am getting the results I expected. Probably nothing to learn here except understand your data better.